# the builder is repeated many times when i want to print data from firebase

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have problem with flutter and firebase.

I want to print data from firebase in flutter interface which contains a form, the data printed successfully but when i want to write in the text-field the loading case don't let me, all the builder will be repeating many times and quickly.

It well print 
loading after form loading after the form ..
And i can't write, so how to solve this problem please?

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Profile"),
      elevation: 1.5,
    ),
    body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .document(widget.user.uid)
          .snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        }
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Text('Loading.. '); 
            break;
          default:
            return checkRole(snapshot.data);
            break;
        }
      },
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i soleve this problem by adding snapshot.hasdata

```
builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done ||
            snapshot.hasData) {
          return checkRole(snapshot.data);
        } else {
          return new Center(child: new Text('loading'));
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use FutureBuilder becuase you are trying to fecth a document,

```
FutureBuilder(future: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(widget.user.uid).get(),
            builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){

      if(snapshot.hasData){
          return Text('${snapshot.data.data}');
      }

    return Text('Loading.. '); 

              });
```